# How does one factorise expressions of a certain form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ 2x^2 + 5xy + 3y^2 $$

$$ (p+q)^2 + 5p(p+q) $$

Can someone please help me factorize these expressions? 
I understand how to factorize polynomials well, such as $3x^2 + 7x + 8 $ however I cannot seem to work out these because they are weird.

It would be well appreciated if someone could help me understand how to tackle these questions as I have my GCSE exams coming up soon, thanks ^^.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, you can factorise it directly. However, you may find it easier to write $x = zy$ to visualise what's going on.

So the expression $2x^2 + 5xy + 3y^2$ becomes $2z^2y^2 + 5zy^2 + 3y^2 = y^2(2z^2 + 5z + 3) = (y^2)(2z+3)(z+1)= (y)(2z + 3)(y)(z+1) =  (2zy+3y)(zy+y) = (2x+3y)(x+y)$

This technique of rewriting variables in terms of one another (and including an extra 'dummy' variable) is a useful one when you're finding it difficult to visualise something.

For the second, just group like factors together:

$(p+q)^2 + 5p(p+q) = (p+q)(p+q + 5p) = (p+q)(6p+q)$.